# Doctrine save aggregate root and entities on same table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a `Trip` entity related to table `trips`. Unfortunately the table structure is huge (38 fields).

I can descompose the trip into several entities, so a trip has some composition entities like `Route` instead of originAddress, originLatitude, originLongitude, destinationAddress, etc...

But I don't know if would be possible to map the ORM (`Doctrine`) to these fields on the same table. AFAIK one entity can be only related to a table and viceversa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with [Embeddables](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/embeddables.html).

From the AR using `@embeddable` attributes which point to another `@embedded` entities. With @embedded you can specify to which columns of database you can map the fields. This way you can use composition to several classes which will map to the same record on the database.